# Remove symbols entered in input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to prevent some symbols entered in a input field to appear. When user types something in input, I need to check if it meets a certain criteria and if it does - symbol should appear in input (as usual), but if not - nothing should happen.

So is there some event that I can catch before typed symbol appears in input?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ueyvq5vNjWoNSHkyEyM7?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="changeExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('changeExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.var = 'a';
      }])

      .directive('changeValue', function() {
        return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            elem.on('input', function() {
              if(ctrl.$viewValue !== 'a') {
                scope.var = '';
              }
            });

            ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
              return value === 'a' ? value : '';
            });
          }
        }
      });
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="confirmed" change-value ng-change="change()"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ueyvq5vNjWoNSHkyEyM7?p=preview)

Comment: I've edited a huge part of your question. Please, feel free to edit again if I've missed your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I think, that's what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ngChange` directive to identify and remove undesired chars.

In the example below, the input field will not accept the `$` sign.

```js
angular.module('changeExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    var FORBIDDEN_SYMBOL = '$';
      
    $scope.change = function () {

      var newChar = $scope.confirmed.slice(-1);

      if (newChar === FORBIDDEN_SYMBOL) {
      
        var inputSize = $scope.confirmed.length;
        $scope.confirmed = $scope.confirmed.substring(0, inputSize -1);
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="changeExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" />
</div>
```